# Recycler View Scrolling do not collapse tablayout, toolbar and ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

My Recycler View has 4 items and When I scroll up Toolbar, Image and TabLayout should collapse. but they dont. when I touch TabLayout or ImageView and scroll up it collapse. sometimes recyclerView collapse above mentioned view and sometimes dont. when I just fling it dont. But when I scroll recyclerview it sometimes collapse views. I have checked many blogs and tried different scroll_flags and their combination. also tried setNestedScroll(true) for recyclerview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/banner_android"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"

            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                android:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="10dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="10dp" />

        <!--app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"-->
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nev_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as shown below

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"

            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
           />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:contentInsetStart="48dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_main2"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Dear i HAVE to scroll views along with recycler view scrolling and its not working for me using above code(posted by me). this is my question.

Comment: in my code, tab layout remains the same, everything else will get collapsed. i thought that is your case. can you clarify me? @HammadTariq

Comment: After AppBarLayout. I have recyclerView. if i scroll it or down views dont get collapsed. this is my issue. however i have added layout_behaviour in recyclerview.

Comment: do checked my code? What are the differences you have found in my code with respect to your desired output, just asking just because i don't get you clearly. @HammadTariq